# Change option values as per the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change option values as per the input value. For example if i put `value02` in input then the select should show options having `title="value02"` other options will hide.

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" value="" id="fname">

<select name="program" id="program">
  <option>Select Program Type</option>
  <option value="1" title="value01">1</option>
  <option value="2" title="value01">2</option>
  <option value="1" title="value02">1</option>
  <option value="2" title="value02">2</option>
  <option value="1" title="value03">1</option>
  <option value="2" title="value03">2</option>
</select>
```

Please help

Comment: If you show what you have tried so far, you will be more likely to get a response. Try the solution yourself and if you run into a specific problem, then ask the question

Comment: @Suresh Mali, Check my Answer it would be helpful for sure.

Comment: Suresh, you've received five answers in 8 hours, but you've not responded to any of them.  That is not how the StackOverflow site works best.  When you post a question, you should be interacting with the people providing answers to make sure they are answering the question you intended.  And, if one of these answers is what you needed, then you should select it as the best answer by checking the green checkmark next to it.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry i seen all the answers just now.. yesterday i left the office immediately after posting the question..

Comment: @SureshMali - that really isn't the right way to use StackOverflow.  If your question was not entirely clear, it would have been closed by now.  You should only post when you can monitor StackOverflow for at least the next 30-45 minutes so you can clarify any issues, respond to questions, direct any answers that aren't what you were expecting while the people who provided the answers are likely still around, etc...  Anyway, glad you're back - hope you can provide feedback on the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the ANSWER you looking for

[WORKING:DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6vmu5650/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="" id="fname">
<select name="program" id="program">
    <option>Select Program Type</option>
    <option value="1" title="value01">01 1</option>
    <option value="2" title="value01">01 2</option>
    <option value="1" title="value02">02 1</option>
    <option value="2" title="value02">02 2</option>
    <option value="1" title="value03">03 1</option>
    <option value="2" title="value03">03 2</option>
</select>
```

**JS/JQuery**

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("select");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
         $("#program option[title='value01']").show();
         $("#program option[title='value02']").show();
         $("#program option[title='value03']").show();
    }
}); 

$("select").click(function()
{
var getVal = $("input[type=text]").val();
    if(getVal == "value01")
    {
        $("#program option[title='value02']").hide();
        $("#program option[title='value03']").hide();
    }
    else if(getVal == "value02")
    {
        $("#program option[title='value01']").hide();
        $("#program option[title='value03']").hide();
    }
    else if(getVal == "value03")
    {
        $("#program option[title='value01']").hide();
        $("#program option[title='value02']").hide();        
    }
    else
    {
    }

});
```

Comment: @SureshMali, I'm curious why you selected an answer that hard-codes the specific title values in the JS rather than one that works with any title values you happen to have in your HTML.  The hard-coded option is a lot less flexible and more work to maintain if your HTML is modified.  In general, you would like your JS to automatically handle changes to the HTML if possible (which it is in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery. Get the value of the `input` and search the `option` for that value and set the value. Try with -

```
$('#program').val($('#program option[title=' + $('#fname').val() + ']').val())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question means that you want to hide `<option>` tags that don't match the title that the user typed (so only the matching options are available in the `<select>`), you can do it like this:

You can monitor changes to the fname field and upon each change see if the current value of the fname field matches any of the titles and, if so, hide the options that don't match, leaving only the matching options.  If none match, then show all the options.

```
$("#fname").on("input", function() {
    var option;
    if (this.value) {
        var sel = $("#program");
        option = sel.find('option[title="' + this.value + '"]');
    }
    if (option && option.length) {
        // show only the matching options
        sel.find("option").hide();
        option.show();
    } else {
        // show all options
        sel.find("option").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="" id="fname">

        <select name="program" id="program">
        <option>Select Program Type</option>
        <option value="1" title="value01">1</option>
        <option value="2" title="value01">2</option>
        <option value="1" title="value02">1</option>
        <option value="2" title="value02">2</option>
        <option value="1" title="value03">1</option>
        <option value="2" title="value03">2</option>
        </select>
   $('#fname').on('blur', function(){
 var value=$("#fname").val();    

     $('#program').val($('#program option[title=' + value + ']').val());


});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/qrecL29u/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It disables all the options. And add new option that is entered from input field. You need to press enter after entering value in input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#fname').bind('keypress', function(e) {

    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode

      $("#program").append($('<option/>', {
        value: $("#fname").val(),
        title: $("#fname").val(),
        text: $("#fname").val()
      }));
      $("#program option[value!=" + $("#fname").val() + "]").attr('disabled', true);
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fname" value="" id="fname">

<select name="program" id="program">
  <option>Select Program Type</option>
  <option value="1" title="value01">1</option>
  <option value="2" title="value01">2</option>
  <option value="1" title="value02">1</option>
  <option value="2" title="value02">2</option>
  <option value="1" title="value03">1</option>
  <option value="2" title="value03">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

And without jQuery

```js
var field = document.getElementById('fname'),
  select = document.getElementById('program');
field.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
  for (var i = 0; i < select.children.length; i++) {
    if (select.children[i].title !== field.value) select.children[i].style.display = 'none';
    else select.children[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fname" value="" id="fname">
<select name="program" id="program">
  <option>Select Program Type</option>
  <option value="1" title="value01">1</option>
  <option value="2" title="value01">2</option>
  <option value="1" title="value02">1</option>
  <option value="2" title="value02">2</option>
  <option value="1" title="value03">1</option>
  <option value="2" title="value03">2</option>
</select>
```